# When try to call getCapabilitiesForType which got crash?

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

When I try get mediecodec info , Always crash, But don't know why ?

```
MediaCodecInfo info = null;
CodecCapabilities capabilities;
  try {

    Logging.e(TAG, " 22222222222222222222;");

    capabilities = info.getCapabilitiesForType(mime);
    Logging.e(TAG, " 3333333333333333333333333333333333333;");

    Logging.e(TAG, " capabilities = info.getCapabilitiesForType(mime);");
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Logging.e(TAG, "Cannot retrieve encoder capabilities", e);
    continue;
  }
```

Folllow is Crash stack:

> 1-02 12:38:24.849 4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #00  pc 00022e38 
>   /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+15) 11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/?
>   I/DEBUG:     #01  pc 00026583  /system/lib/libc.so (sscanf+34) 11-02
>   12:38:24.850 4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #02  pc 00010b93 
>   /system/lib/hw/camera.bigfish.so 11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/?
>   I/DEBUG:     #03  pc 00011ddb  /system/lib/hw/camera.bigfish.so
>   (android::CameraParameterPreview::queryCapability(android::CameraParameters&)+298)
>   11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #04  pc 00012bf9 
>   /system/lib/hw/camera.bigfish.so
>   (android::CapabilityManager::queryCap(android::CameraParameters&)+56)
>   11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #05  pc 0000c8b7 
>   /system/lib/hw/camera.bigfish.so
>   (android::CameraHal::initDefaultParameters()+18) 11-02 12:38:24.850
>   4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #06  pc 0000e81b 
>   /system/lib/hw/camera.bigfish.so
>   (android::CameraHal::CameraHal(int)+554) 11-02 12:38:24.850
>   4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #07  pc 0000eafd 
>   /system/lib/hw/camera.bigfish.so 11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/?
>   I/DEBUG:     #08  pc 00044875  /system/lib/libcameraservice.so
>   (android::CameraClient::initialize(camera_module*)+180) 11-02
>   12:38:24.850 4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #09  pc 0003e493 
>   /system/lib/libcameraservice.so
>   (android::CameraService::connectFinishUnsafe(android::sp
>   const&, android::sp const&)+16) 11-02 12:38:24.850
>   4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #10  pc 000402a7 
>   /system/lib/libcameraservice.so
>   (android::CameraService::connect(android::sp
>   const&, int, android::String16 const&, int,
>   android::sp&)+494) 11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/?
>   I/DEBUG:     #11  pc 00021943  /system/lib/libcamera_client.so
>   (android::BnCameraService::onTransact(unsigned int, android::Parcel
>   const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+314) 11-02 12:38:24.850
>   4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #12  pc 0003dfb1 
>   /system/lib/libcameraservice.so
>   (android::CameraService::onTransact(unsigned int, android::Parcel
>   const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+104) 11-02 12:38:24.850
>   4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #13  pc 00019225  /system/lib/libbinder.so
>   (android::BBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&,
>   android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+60) 11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/?
>   I/DEBUG:     #14  pc 0001d799  /system/lib/libbinder.so
>   (android::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int)+508) 11-02 12:38:24.850
>   4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #15  pc 0001db17  /system/lib/libbinder.so
>   (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+38) 11-02
>   12:38:24.850 4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #16  pc 0001db8d 
>   /system/lib/libbinder.so
>   (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48) 11-02 12:38:24.850
>   4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #17  pc 000219a5  /system/lib/libbinder.so
>   11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #18  pc 0000ea5d 
>   /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
>   11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #19  pc 0000e58f 
>   /system/lib/libutils.so 11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:
>
> ## 20  pc 0000d228  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72) 11-02 12:38:24.850 4583-4583/? I/DEBUG:     #21  pc 0000d3c0
>
> /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

Comment: info is null check in your code

Comment: intialize `MediaCodecInfo info` before calling `info.getCapabilitiesForType(mime)`